# camel producer is not working while processing a json

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I want to read an Excel file and convert it to a json file through camel REST. But when I tried to access the API inside my route it's saying:

> Route: route1 started and consuming from: servlet: /api/convertFile

After this no progress is happening.

I have tried as below:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("rest:get:/api/convertFile?host=http://localhost:8080").autoStartup(false).setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, simple(queryparams).process(jsonProcessor);
}
```

I am expecting after hitting the rest endpoint, it will process the Excel file to json file.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What Camel version?
How do you call the rest endpoint? Note that you have declared the rest as a GET which mean there is no payload, so if you want to upload a file, then you likely want to use POST instead

Comment: @Claus Ibsen, I am using 3.3.0 as Camel version. I want to use this rest end point as Producer, so that it can be processed to produce the json.

Comment: Camel 3.3.0 is very old, if you can try with latest 3.x release like 3.20.3, or 3.14.x if you must stay on Java 8.